# Is a way to set Connection refused time to HTTPGet Apache ?

Tags: java, apache, web-crawler, http-get, connection-refused

I want to get a web page but if return Connection refused I want to wait only 1 second

My code :

```
final DefaultHttpClient client = HTTPSHelper.getClientThatAllowAnyHTTPS(connectionManager);
        client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,
                CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

        client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 1000);
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", 1000);
        client.addRequestInterceptor(new RequestAcceptEncoding());
        client.addResponseInterceptor(new ResponseContentEncoding());

final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.getUrl());
            final HttpResponse resp = this.httpClient.execute(get, localContext);
```

When returns connection refused I have to wait a lot ...Is there a way to specify time to wait on connection refused ? Thanks

Comment: 'Connection refused' should happen  within a second or two. Are you sure it isn't 'connection timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timeout for the connection this way:

```
final HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
 HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(p, 1000); 
client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams) ;
```